# Adding the constant column increases the rank of symmetric non-full ranked matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Assume we have some symmetric Laplacian matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $rank(A) = n-1$.

Then, let us consider matrix $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1\times n}$, which is matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with one more constant non zero row added.

Will we have then  $rank(B) = n$? Below, I have a simple R code for the A matrix

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
2  & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2  & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then, adding the row with all elements equal to one increases the rank. I do not understand.

```
data = c(2,-1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 2)
A = matrix(data,nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE) 
print(A)
rankMatrix(A)
B = rbind(A, rep(1,3))
print(B)
rankMatrix(B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a row increases the dimension of the output vector by $1$, however the matrix would only "increase" in *rank* if this row was linearly independent to the $n-1$ independent rows. The rank can't be continually increased however. The largest possible rank for an $m\times n$ matrix is $\min(m,n)$ since the rank cannot be larger than the dimension of output vector nor can the matrix "*increase*" the "size" of the domain (the "input" vector space) by making the rank larger than the domain dimension. This is because linear maps are well-defined and have only one output vector per input vector

Answer (score 0):

> If the sum of the entries of your new row is $0$ then $\text{rank}(B) = \text{rank}(A) = n-1$.

To prove that statement:

- Prove that the nulspace of $A$, $N(A)$ is generated by the vector $\left(1,\ldots,1\right)$.
- Since $A$ is symmetric the row space of $A$ is the orthogonal complementary of $N(A)$.

Comment: the sun is not zero. It is important that the row added is constant

Comment: What do you mean by the row is constant. If the sum is not zero, then rank will be $n$

Answer (score 0):

When we take Matrix A & **"ADD"** Column 2 & Column 3 to Column 1 , we see that Column 1 is totally **ZERO**.
Hence Column 3 is not **"INDEPENDENT"** of the other Columns.
Hence Matrix A is not full rank.

When we **"APPEND"** a new row of $(0,0,0)$ to get Matrix B , adding Column 2 & Column 3 to Column 1 will still give Column 1 **Zero** hence it will still not be full rank.

When we **"APPEND"** a new row of $(1,1,1)$ to get Matrix B , adding Column 2 & Column 3 to Column 1 will not make Column 1 **Zero** , because the last element in that Column will be $1+1+1=3$.
In other words , the new row makes the Column 1 **"INDEPENDENT"** of the other Columns.
Hence the rank of matrix B will **INCREASE** by 1.

ADDENDUM :
When we alternatively append a row like $(0,+a,-a)$ , we will end up with Zero Column 1 when we add the 2 Column & Column 3 to Column 1 , because $0+a-a=0$
More generally , we might append a row like $a+b,-a,-b$ , where we still have $(a+b)-a-b=0$
It will not Change the rank.

**All other types of rows will Increase the rank by 1.**